# Delete Photos from My Pics Directory

Tags: linux

I have photos uploaded that need to be deleted. These photos all have names. I have entered the following language to begin the process of removing the photos.

```
vs2:/u/p/jjones % cd www.thetether.com/cgi-bin 
                % cd ../pics
```

I pressed return and got the following language.

```
vs2:/u/p/jjones/www.thetether.com/pics %
```

To that line of language I added a space after % and then the name of the photo file as follows.

```
ds0718.htm
```

I then hit return and got a "Command not found." message.

Is there a cure for this problem?

Comment: Is ds0718.htm *really* the name of a photo? (It could be, just seems suspicious.) run `file ds0718.htm` to see what the contents appear to be.

Comment: Jeff has a good point — that is very likely HTML file (the markup language used to create web pages), given th extension.

Comment: Also, `cd www.thetether.com/cgi-bin` followed by `cd ../pics` is exactly the same as just saying `cd www.thetether.com/pics` in the first place. The `..` means "go back up one directory"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that simply entering the filename doesn't *act* on it, or bring up a list of options like "delete" or "rename". That's a reasonable-enough guess, but it just doesn't work that way. You need to enter a *command* and then give a filename. In this case, the command you want is `rm`, so at your prompt after changing to the pics directory, you would type `rm ds0718.htm`.

I would recommend spending a few minutes looking at basic Linux/Unix command guides, [like this one](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/basic-unix.html) or [this one](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/).